# How to rename a file using a java while it is open

Tags: java

In my java code, I am using renameTo method to rename the file. I am able to do it successfully if the file is closed physically. But I am unable to do so if the file I am trying to rename is open.

How do I close the file thru code?

This is the code :

```
File file = new File("/users/abc.txt");
File newFile = new File("/users/xyz.txt");
if (file.renameTo(newFile)) {
    System.out.println("File rename success");
} else {
    System.out.println("File rename failed");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you can't do that. To apply changes to a file, it cannot be opened by another entity. Besides - why would you want that? What's wrong with closing the file and *then* renaming it?

Comment: This is the same file which is used whenever the application runs. It is a DB file and If it was already open when the application starts, then renaming it fails.

Comment: The operating system does not allow what you want to do.

Comment: Then close it in the application, rename it, and reopen it again?

Comment: The behavior of the method "renameTo" are inherently platform-dependent. For an example, this renaming works fine on MacBook with the file to be renamed already open with Sublime text or TextEdit and though the same code does not work on Windows.

Comment: Hi Fureeish, that is what I am looking for. How do you close the file from the application?

Comment: By the way. Do you have to rename it, or could you move it instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot close a file in Java that is opened by another user. It is highly platform dependant, it is impossible if that user/process has higher priviledges then your process, and the user editing it might hava data loss, if he is in the process of editing that file in an Editor. Don't ever do that.

The only way would be to wait until the file has been closed by that other user like that, however, I still discourage from doing so. If you have to use that file, just exit your application with an error.

```
File file = new File("/users/abc.txt");
File newFile = new File("/users/xyz.txt");
try {
    while (!file.renameTo(newFile)) {
        Thread.sleep(10_000); // wait 10 seconds
    }
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
// ignore
}
```

Comment: It would be important, if this approach is taken to notify the user about the waiting process or advise him to close the related file, otherwise the software will freeze without feedback.

Comment: Yes, there sould be some more reasonable error handling. The whole logic sounds flawed to me.

Comment: However, I had quite a similar problem: In Windows, I had to import data from a certain .*csv file. The problem was that Windows fires the event that a file is created before it was actually completly written by the other party. I had to use some sleeping until the other party closed the file, with a maximum number of attempts.